# PHP - include multiple css files function

Tags: php, function, include

I am trying to make a function which will load my css file easily. I dont have enough knowledge of PHP, so please help me:

I want to call that function as:

```
<?php load_css('reset.css,main.css,bootstrap.css'); ?>
```

Please tell me how do i separate all file name from function parameter and call them one by one. My current function:

```
<?php

load_css($files){

echo '<style src="'.$files.'"></style>';

}

?>
```

Comment: refer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472709/combining-multiple-css-files

Comment: As a side note: remember that spreading your CSS to many files will slow page loading because the browser has to request these files one by one. In the future you may want to look into tools such as [assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic#readme) that compile many JS or CSS files into one. Assetic is included in the popular [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) framework but can also be used separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea here that is short,simple and fast to understand..

```
// store css file names as array..
$css = array('css1','css2','css3');

// then loop to call them one by one.
foreach($css as $style){

    echo '<style src="'.$style.'"></style>';
}
```

Comment: I think `echo '<style src="'.$style.'"></style>';` will be `echo '<style src="'.$css.'"></style>';`

Comment: @user1983017 thats correct im wrong at `foreach($style as $cc)` it should be `foreach($css as $style)`.. thanks for clarification..

Comment: got error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: Working `function load_js($files){
 $css = array($files);
 foreach($css as $style){
  echo '<style src="'.$style.'"></style>';
 }

}`

Comment: @user1983017 thats right you can create a function using this preference.. glad it works..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using traditional HTML css includes instead?

e.g.:

```
@import cssfile-number.css
```

(replace -number with different css filenames or numbers).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Forgot to mention that you need to stick that line in a css file on its own, and then use (a) <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-file.css" /> tag(s) to include the css file that imports css files. Confusing, I know :D !!!

Comment: This is because he wants it to do with php. comment first to be sure if it a option. but +1 for your orthodox answer. I basically prefer it over all. thanks

Answer (score 1):

write your functionlike this

```
<?php

load_css($files){

  $css=explode(",",$file);

  for($i=0;$i<count($css);$i++)
  {
   echo '<style src="'.$css[$i].'"></style>';
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: dont forget to accept answer if it works for you. So it will help others too. Happy Coding :)

Comment: you have a `(` which should be `)`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
load_css($files){
    $files = explode(",", $files);
    while(list($css) = each($files){
        echo "<style type='text/css' src='" . $css . "' ></style>";
    }
}
$css = 'css.css,css1.css,css2.css';
load_css($css);
```

or

```
load_css($files){
    while(list($css) = each($files){
        echo "<style type='text/css' src='" . $css . "' ></style>";
    }
}
$css = array('css.css','css1.css','css2.css');
load_css($css);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this that combine and minify your css and you need only add one css instead several css file on page

css.php

```
<?php 
$now=time()+10000;
$then="Expires: ".gmstrftime("%a,%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT",$now);
header($then); 
header("Cache-Control:  public, must-revalidate"); 
header("Content-Type: text/css");
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
set_time_limit(0);
//list of your css
$CssList=array('main.css',
'simple-lists.css');
$outt='';
foreach($CssList as $CSS){
   $outt.=minify_css($CSS);
}
function minify_css($add){
   $fp=fopen($add,'rb');
   $speed=1024*100;
   while(!feof($fp)){
     $out.=fread($fp,$speed);
   }
   $out = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $out);
   /* remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc. */
   $out = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $out);
   //$out=str_replace("  ","",$out);
   //$out=str_replace("  ","",$out);
   return $out;
}
print($outt);
while (@ob_end_flush());
?>
```

put this on your header

```
<style type="text/css" src="css.php" ></style>
```

Comment: Man, I was thinking for css minify/compression function. And your code just do that. love it, awesome. Thanks